# How change the default desktop manager in debian?

Tags: linux

I am using Debian 6 with two desktop managers (Gnome and KDE). During installation, I chose KDE as the default desktop. But, now I want to change the default desktop to Gnome. How do I change it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the solution by editing the file `default-display-manager` in the path `/etc/X11/`:

```
#vim /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

For Gnome, edit as:

```
/usr/sbin/gdm
```

For KDE, edit as below:

```
/usr/lib/kde4/bin/kdm
```

Once updated, reboot the computer. You can find it updated the display manager.

You can also do it by executing the below command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: And I'm pretty sure gdm allows you to switch from the login screen.

Comment: Also `update-alternatives --configure x-window-manager` should allow you to select which one do you want to be the system default.

Comment: @Wolfer You mean `update-alternatives --config x-window-manage`

Comment: @Mike On my system `update-alternatives --display x-window-manage` outputs `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-window-manage` whereas `update-alternatives --display x-window-manager` reports what one would want to see... For reference this is on sid...

Comment: @Wolfer Sorry, that was a typo on my part. My point is that it is "config" and not "configure".

Comment: `x-window-manager` is not a **X display manager** (or "X Desktop Manager", as in question)

Answer (score 10):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager`

This uses Debian's built-in mechanisms to choose "alternatives" for default commands.

Comment: Answer is taken from nearby comments of Wolfer and Mike. Since this is the preferrable solution, it'd better be posted as one.

Comment: Annnnnnnnnd, NOPE! Making this change had no effect at all.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer is likely:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

assuming that "desktop manager" (which is not a meaningful term under X11) refers to the *desktop environment* (both KDE and GNOME are desktop environments, not window managers nor display managers).

Only when `x-session-manager` doesn't exist does Debian GNU/Linux fall back to `x-window-manager` or even `x-terminal-emulator`.

Historical note: What Debian GNU/Linux refers to as session manager is not actually a session manager in the X11 sense, but it's the term used by most modern GNU/Linux distributions to refer to a desktop environment, which typically includes a window manager, file manager, compositing manager, panels and other amenities.

Comment: Likely, and, wrong. Yes, this let me pick LDXE from a list. Which accomplished nothing, as my machine continued to boot into Gnome regardless.

Comment: The "likely" referred to the question using an undefined term ("desktop manager"). Your argument is also a non-sequitur, because changing the default only takes effect when the default is used, so your machine still booting into gnome just means you are not booting into the default environment, but gnome was selected over the default.